# Are LQFP100 and PQFP100 the same footprint?

Tags: packages

Currently laying out a board. The data sheet footprint of the device is LQFP100 but the nearest I have in the layout package is PQFP100. Looking on the Net, they appear to be the same, but are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same footprint. If you check the sizes of the two packages you will see that the LQFP is thinner.